# Creating a bounding box in image with transparency

Tags: c++, winapi, image-processing

I want to crop an image with one specific color acting like a transparency mask and I would like to create the smallest box that will enclose the image.

A picture of what I mean will explain it better for sure:

[image: Images with bounding boxes]

The RGB(255,0,255) is the transparent mask and the green frames represent the desired bounding box.

I've already figured out the top line of the bounding box:

```
    int nAlloc = (128 * 128) * 4;
    unsigned char* buf = new unsigned char[nAlloc];
    GetBitmapBits(hBMP, nAlloc, buf);
    for(int i = 0; i < nAlloc; i += 4)
    {
        if(buf[i] == 255 && buf[i + 1] == 0 && buf[i + 2] == 255)
        {
            continue;
        }
        // If I hit a first non-transparent pixel, 
        // I can then calculate the row where is that pixel located.
        else if(set_pixel == false)
        {
            set_pixel = true;
            index = ceil((float)(i / 4.0 / 128.0));
        }
        ... // Converting non-transparent pixels to Black&White
    }

    //I'm then drawing the bitmap to window like so:
    TransparentBlt(hdc, 5, 305 - index, 128, 128, hDC, 0, 0, 128, 128, RGB(255, 0, 255));
```

I think, I know how to determine the last row as well but I'm not sure with that and have no idea how to find out the sides of the bounding box.

Comment: You could probably use a [flood fill](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Flood_fill#/The_algorithm) algorithm (this problem is kind of an inverse flood fill).

Comment: @JonathanPotter That does not give me the bounding lines, right? I don't want to affect any pixels, I just want to get the bounging box. This is too complex for this issue I believe.

Comment: You wouldn't actually do any filling, but the recursive algorithm would let you find the edges of the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to find the bounding box of your image you just have to go through your image row-wise and column-wise until you find a nontransparent pixel.
By doing this you can get the min and max values of your Bounding Box.

```
RECT BoundingBox = { 0,0,0,0 };
const int nAlloc = (128 * 128) * 4;
unsigned char* buf = new unsigned char[nAlloc];
GetBitmapBits(hBMP, nAlloc, buf);

bool found;

//search upper bound
found = false;
for (int row = 0; row<128 && !found; row++) //row
{
    for (int col = 0; col<128 && !found; col++) //column
    {
        int idx = (row * 128 + col) * 4;
        if (!(buf[idx] == 255 && buf[idx + 1] == 0 && buf[idx + 2] == 255)) //not transparent
        {
            BoundingBox.top = row;
            found = true;
        }
    }
}

//search lower bound
found = false;
for (int row = 127; row >= 0 && !found; row--) //row
{
    for (int col = 127; col >= 0 && !found; col--) //column
    {
        int idx = (row * 128 + col) * 4;
        if (!(buf[idx] == 255 && buf[idx + 1] == 0 && buf[idx + 2] == 255)) //not transparent           {
            BoundingBox.bottom = row;
            found = true;
        }
    }
}


//search left bound
found = false;
for (int col = 0; col<128 && !found; col++) //row
{
    for (int row = 0; row<128 && !found; row++) //column
    {
        int idx = (row * 128 + col) * 4;
        if (!(buf[idx] == 255 && buf[idx + 1] == 0 && buf[idx + 2] == 255)) //not transparent           {
            BoundingBox.left = col;
            found = true;
        }
    }
}


//search right bound
found = false;
for (int col = 127; col >= 0 && !found; col--) //row
{
    for (int row = 127; row >= 0 && !found; row--) //column
    {
        int idx = (row * 128 + col) * 4;
        if (!(buf[idx] == 255 && buf[idx + 1] == 0 && buf[idx + 2] == 255)) //not transparent           {
            BoundingBox.right = col;
            found = true;
        }
    }
}

//now the variable "BoundingBox" contains your BoundingBox
```

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: This one is nice, but it doesn't actually solve my problem. I need to find the sides too. Not just the top and bottom which I already have as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: But there are the sides too in this code if you scroll down

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if there's an elegant way of doing this but you can simply scan whole image, and while doing so record min and max columns for non transparent pixels.

```
const int rowcnt = 128;
const int colcnt = 128;
const int bytesperpix = 4;
int pos = 0;
int colmin = colcnt;
int colmax = 0;
int colpos = 0;
for(int r = 0; r < rowcnt; ++r)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < colcnt * bytesperpix; c += 4)
    {
        pos = r * colcnt * bytesperpix + c;
        if(buf[pos] == 255 && buf[pos + 1] == 0 && buf[pos + 2] == 255)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            colpos = c / bytesperpix;
            if(colpos < colmin)
                colmin = colpos;
            else if(colpos > colmax)
                colmax = colpos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not going to work. The bitmap has 4 bytes only in one dimensoin. So when you're iterating in the column, it should be just from 0 to 127. When I tried the code before without further looking at it, it allways hits the second if statement.

Comment: i revised the code. now it iterates rows from 0 to 128 and columns from 0 to 512.

Comment: It still fulfills the second condition. The colmax is equal to value 65532 after this loop.

Comment: i hope you copied whole code because i changed some mistakes at other places too.